# How can I increase the throughput/bandwith of my virtual network?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, bandwidth, virtual-network

I have some virtual machines servers with some micro-services and do some load tests with JMeter. All the servers including the JMeter machine are sharing the same virtual network. The virtual network has no adapters:

[image]

The problem is that it seems to be a ceiling on traffic throughput  at 320Mbit/sec (`iftop -i interface`):
[image]

I set up the traffic shaping very big just to be sure that it doesn't put any limitation
[image]
How can I increase the throughput of my virtual network to go over this 320Mbit/sec limitation?

Comment: What's the host spec? You should easily be able to handle multiple 10Gbps traffic flows with this setup - have you installed the latest vmtools into each guest?

Comment: @Chopper3  HP ProLiant BL460C Gen9 20 CPUs x 2.297 GHz all virtual servers have 4CPUs and VMXNET3 interfaces

Comment: Very odd, we have the same blade and don't seem to be getting that kind of issue - you're on ESXi 6.0u2 right? have you tried any other test tool?

Comment: @Chopper3 I tested on another server with real 1Gbit interfaces and the tools could keep up with the bandwidth

Comment: I'd still be tempted to test using some other tool or another - almost anything else, just in case there's something odd about it - feel free to show us more vSS details if you like.

Comment: ah - thanks for that update - why have you set ANY traffic shaping unless you need it - it's computationally 'expensive' - disable it and retest please

Comment: @Chopper3 the problem was indeed with one of my tools, now I can get 10.6Gb, can you put your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have solved the tool issue, I might add that for maximum performance inside a vSwitch in VMware, make sure that you're running the latest vmtools and VMXNET3 adapters (the legacy e1000 adapters are kinda slow comparatively).

Here's an interesting comparison;
http://rickardnobel.se/vmxnet3-vs-e1000e-and-e1000-part-2/