# How to improve bandwidth performance for a vm

Tags: vmware-esxi, bandwidth

I have been told to add additional nics to the VM to improve bandwidth performance. Once they are added what is the best way to team them together for best performance?

I tried the Microsoft bridge and it didn't work very well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

a) Don't do this, that's not how to do this at all, b) there's no guarantee any change will work until you show us how things are connected to your VSS/VDS and the uplink ports, either way you don't do in-VM bonding, bad idea all-round.

Comment: We have 2 vSwitches the management network with 2x1Gbe ports (no lag) and the machine network with 4x10gbe ports (lag).

Comment: Still a fraction of what we'd need to help you, you need to look at how the site works and what we expect from question-askers, have a look at the help pages and observe the workings of the site - then you'll realise how little you've given us to help you.

Comment: I have a host with a VM that has teh vmxnet3 driver loaded, its primary purpose is as a file server .. pushing big files out. The VM network / port group is connected to a vswitch with 4 10gbe ports that are connected to a 10gbe switch, and are in a lag group. I am using the IP Hash method and everything is working. I just want to speed up the file transfer for the File Server VM.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/797645/how-can-i-increase-the-throughput-bandwith-of-my-virtual-network?rq=1. This is a thread you answered and I feel I have provided at least as much information as they provided. Did I meet your expectations?